# How to get shortcut to point to the correct program in Windows on access install

Tags: microsoft-access, windows-7, runtime

I'm having an issue with a program installed on someone else's pc with the Microsoft Access runtime. The runtime that comes with the program is Microsoft access 2007. However, once the program is is installed, the shortcut points to the office 2010 version of the runtime, which is incompatible.

Edit: changed question to what it really should be.

How can I change the install routine to make the shortcut's target type point to the 2007 runtime that comes with the download?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the shortcut and click on Properties.
2. Click on the Shortcut tab there.
3. In the Target field, type the full path of the original file (Microsoft access 2007).
4. Click on OK to apply.

Comment: Unfortunately, the target is correct, it's the accdr file. I need to change the *target type*, which I believe is the 2010 runtime. Or actually, which runtime that target type points to.

Comment: You need to look at "how to change a file association". http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=change+file+association